# Power BI Connector - The remote server returned an error: (404)

Tags: jira

I'm having trouble using JIRA's Power BI Connector to extract information for a dashboard in Power BI.

Here's the error below:

> DataSource.Error:
> Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Resources.HttpResource: Falha na
> solicitação: Versão do OData: 3 e 4, Erro: O servidor remoto retornou
> um erro: (404) Não Localizado. Versão do OData: 4, Erro: O servidor
> remoto retornou um erro: (404) Não Localizado. Versão do OData: 3,
> Erro: O servidor remoto retornou um erro: (404) Não Localizado.

Can anyone help me resolve this error?